# Custom tab intent crashing on chrome version 94.0.4606.80 on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome

Below are the logs after updating chrome to 94.0.4606.80
On Opening CustomTabIntent and start typing the password in password field app crashes.
Any workaround for time being.

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.android.chrome:layout/0_resource_name_obfuscated: Binary XML file line #6 in com.android.chrome:layout/0_resource_name_obfuscated: Error inflating class org.chromium.chrome.browser.keyboard_accessory.tab_layout_component.KeyboardAccessoryTabLayoutView

Comment: I am also getting this. It results in `Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL)` No solutions I have found. We do not have luxury of letting users open in chrome. Custom Tabs is supposed to prevent that for security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution but this issue is being tracked in Chromium issue tracker.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1258176&q=KeyboardAccessoryTabLayoutView&can=2

Let's hope there is a fix soon.

From what I can tell this version of chrome has been pulled from the app store. After uninstalling Chrome and reinstalling my version is `94.0.4606.71`.

If this does not work there are other alternatives for trying to install old versions of Chrome.

Comment: Which language you have used? Java or Kotlin?

Comment: There is no code fix for this bug that I can find. You need an older version of Chrome on your device. 
From what I can tell the version `94.0.4606.80` is not being installed on devices. 
So simply uninstalling chrome and reinstalling might work.